# Get class under a specific id

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fetch a class under specific id. There will be multiple instances of the html code below. The only things that are unique to each instances are the id of the top most `img` and `myModal`. So the next appearance will be where `id = 2` and myModal becomes `myModal2`.

**HTML**

```
  <img class="hover-shadow cursor card-img-top" src="images/dmc.png" id="1" onclick="openModal(this.id);currentSlide(1)" alt="">
                    <div id="myModal1" class="modal">
                        <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <!-- main_slide -->
                          <div class="mySlides">
                            <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
                            <img src="images/dmc.png" style="width:100%">
                          </div>

                          <div class="mySlides">
                            <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
                            <img src="images/port.jpg" style="width:100%">
                          </div>

                          <div class="mySlides">
                            <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
                            <img src="images/dmc.png" style="width:100%">
                          </div>

                          <div class="mySlides">
                            <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
                            <img src="images/port.jpg" style="width:100%">
                          </div>

                          <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                          <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

                          <div class="caption-container">
                            <p class="caption"></p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                          <!-- Thumbnail image slide preview -->
                          <div class="column">
                            <img class="demo cursor" src="images/dmc.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
                          </div>
                          <div class="column">
                            <img class="demo cursor" src="images/port.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
                          </div>
                          <div class="column">
                            <img class="demo cursor" src="images/dmc.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
                          </div>
                          <div class="column">
                            <img class="demo cursor" src="images/port.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
                          </div>


                    </div>
```

**JS file**

```
var thismodal = "myModal";
var clicked_id,trueModalId;
function openModal(clicked_id) {
    trueModalId = thismodal + clicked_id;
    document.getElementById(trueModalId).style.display = "block";
    var thisSlides = "mySlides" + clicked_id;
    alert(thisSlides);
}

function closeModal() {
    document.getElementById(trueModalId).style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    // alert(mySlides);
    var slides = document.getElementById(trueModalId).document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");//display big
    var dots = document.getElementById(trueModalId).document.getElementsByClassName("demo");//thumbnail underneath display big
    var captionText = document.getElementById(trueModalId).document.getElementById("caption");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

It doesn't work when I assigned `slides`, `dots` and `captionText` to `document.getElementById(trueModalId).document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");`, `document.getElementById(trueModalId).document.getElementsByClassName("demo");` and `document.getElementById(trueModalId).document.getElementById("caption");` respectively. What should I do?

**EDIT**

Instead of using `document.getElementById(trueModalId).document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");`, I used `document.querySelectorAll('#' + trueModalId + ' >.modal-content > .mySlides');` and it works.

But in the case of `var captionText = document.querySelectorAll('#' + trueModalId + ' >.modal-content > .caption-container > .caption');`, it doesn't work.

Comment: what class are you talking about?

Comment: Also why tag with jquery when you aren't using it?

Comment: _What am I doing wrong here?_ Explaining the problem, missing a [mcve], ....

Comment: Please provide a proper explanation and a little more description about the issue you are facing.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt Sorry, I have modified my question. Hope its clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the question. As it's really unclear what you are asking for? But there's an answer for you if you want to check for specific class under the specific element:

```
if($('#your_id').find('.your_class').length) {
// do stuff
}
```